# How to get width of the main UIView in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, landscape

When I use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGFloat mainViewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%f", mainViewWidth);
}
```

I got the result in simulator:480

and when i start the app on my iPhone 4 i got the result 320?

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Instead of bounds use frame

Comment: I tried, but result still was not same.

Comment: You should use this piece of code in viewWillAppear because whenever you rotate the call will be there.Or, if you specifically want log on particular orientation then just use a bool value...I hope you get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do the same in `viewWillAppear`.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGFloat mainViewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%f", mainViewWidth);
}
```

and see if you are getting correct values.. `ViewDidLoad` gets called before view is drawn completely. Accessing `UIView` size property gives you unpredictable values there.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.1 :

```
let width = yourView.bounds.width
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
}
```